# I have a problem with flexbox and responsive interface

Tags: html, css, flexbox

hello everybody  I have a problem with flexbox and responsive .....this the picture:

[image]

I would the red section and the black section with 100% but as you can see I have not... I don't know why...
I need a wrap in the blue and red section so I need to fix a min-with for both
but red and black also if I had used flex:1 1 100% is still as in a picture
can you help me?
So why the red and the black are short of the blue and fuxia? even if I set with:100% or 100vw or flex :1,1, 100%...

Where is my mistake?

```css
body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: rgb(16, 235, 235)
}


.item{    
    height: 500px;
    flex:1 1 100%; 
}
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    background: red;
    width: 100vw;
}

.item1{
    background: red;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap; 
}
.int1item1{
    background: orange;
    flex: 0 1 60%;
    align-self: center;
}
.myText{
    margin-top:50px; 
    text-align: center;
}



.item2{
    background:yellow;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap; 
}

.int1Item2{
    background:blue;
    min-width: 200px; 
    flex: 1 1 40%;
}

.int2Item2{
    background:fuchsia;
    min-width: 400px; 
    flex: 1 1 60%;
}

.item3{
    background:black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="item item1">
      <div class="int1item1">
         here title
         <div class="myText">
            <h2>Fix part</h2>
            <p>
               here some text
            </p>
            <p>
               here some text
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item item2">
      <div class="int1Item2">
         here a text 
      </div>
      <div class="int2Item2">
         here text
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item item3">
   </div>
</div>
```

this is a link of my code:https://repl.it/@matteo1976/test-flex-box

Comment: In your code example they are fullwidth already it seems ? :P

Comment: nop the color  rgb(16, 235, 235) is the body Background I want the black and red in full with

Comment: I see the bug only under 400px in width. So, it seems to be caused by the `min-width:400px` you set on fuchsia block. Set that min-width also on your `.container` or remove that limitation. Also consider the use of media queries: they could help you have more control of your layout

Comment: @ReSedano perfect min-width in container work thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I am a little lost with your question if you are looking to make .item1 100% width (the RED container) then you're missing a width property. 
from line 18 change to this...

```
.item1 {background: red;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap; 
    width: 100vw;
}
```

if this isn't what you meant let me know and I'll take another look.

Comment: Yes I want the red full with the blue and pinc wrap and black full with.... I did `.item{    
    height: 500px;
    flex:1 1 100%; 
}` and I know the poblem is in min-width but I need instead to have wrap for ble and pink